# How can Vuforia SDK 10.15 be used for cloud recognition in iOS (Swift) with insufficient documentation?

Tags: ios, swift, native, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

How can i implement cloud recognition in iOS(Swift) using Vuforia SDK 10.15 ? Current documentation on vuforia website is not clear.

I tried following the documentation for implementing in native but it's not clear how to use the cloud observer.

https://library.vuforia.com/cloud-recognition/working-cloud-recognition

It's not clear in the above document how to integrate the above code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.